# How to circumvent dependency errors in postgres for frequently-changing materialized views?

Tags: postgresql

I have a `MATERIALIZED VIEW` whose columns change frequently.  I'm actually generating it programmatically (see Appendix A), but that's not super important.  Here's an example SQL to generate a simple view:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW IF NOT EXISTS my_view AS
    SELECT random() AS col1, random() AS col2, random() AS col3, random() AS col4, random() AS col5;
```

I would like to reference this view from other constructs in my DB, such as `FUNCTION`s, e.g:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo()
  RETURNS SETOF my_view
  LANGUAGE sql STABLE
  AS $$
    SELECT * FROM my_view;
$$;
```

Now, this function does not depend crucially on the column layout of `my_view`, so there's no need to drop and replace the function if I want to add a column to `my_view`.  However, since `my_view` changes frequently, and postgres tracks the dependencies, it forces me to drop and re-create `foo` every time I update `my_view`.  This is unfortunate, and unnecessary, and creates maintenance headaches, because every time I make a change to `my_view`, I have to `DROP` all of my `FUNCTION`s and re-create them.

Is there a good way to work around this, either by telling `postgres` to stop being so strict for this one use-case, or with some other trick?

##### Appendix A: Example MATERIALIZED VIEW generator

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION make_view(n int)
  RETURNS VOID
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
  rec record;
  mv_sql text;
  all_cols text[];
BEGIN

  EXECUTE $$DROP MATERIALIZED VIEW IF EXISTS my_view;$$;
 
  FOR rec IN 
    SELECT generate_series(1,n) AS i
  LOOP
    all_cols := array_append(all_cols, 
      format('random() AS col%s', rec.i));
  END LOOP;

  mv_sql :=
    $$
      CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW IF NOT EXISTS my_view AS
        SELECT $$; 

  mv_sql := mv_sql || array_to_string(all_cols, ', ');
   
  mv_sql := mv_sql || ';';
     
  raise notice '%', mv_sql; 
  EXECUTE mv_sql;
END
$func$;
```

##### EDIT:

@LaurenzAlbe has asked, so, my actual use case is that I have many "types" with postGIS geometries in them.  Currently, each "type" is in a separate table (I could further normalize this, but that doesn't solve this immediate problem).  Each "type" has many geometries that are mutually disjoint (within the type).  I have another large table with points in them.  I need to be able to query "which geometry is point 1 in, for each of my many geometries?".  This is a very slow query, even with the spatial index, so I am `MATERIALIZING` it.  In the normalized form, it looks like `(geo_type text, geo_type_id int, point_id)`, where `(geo_type, geo_type_id)` refers to a unique geometry in said geometry tables, and the existence of a row in this normalized table asserts that the point referenced with `point_id` intersects the geometry referenced by `(geo_type, geo_type_id)`.  Now, when I search for `point`s, I actually need to query against many other variables related to said `point` (which are sundry: there are dates associated with each point, and an "organism" and various other tidbits).  My options are to 1) `JOIN` my `points` table with the normalized `VIEW` at runtime, which prevents me from creating indexes that span the geometry/daterange/etc concepts, 2) `MATERIALIZE` the no-filters `JOIN` from 1), which is absolutely gigantic because my `points` table is large, and the number of available geometry tables is large, and so the `JOIN`ed `VIEW` duplicates all `points` for each `geometry` table. 3) `MATERIALIZE` my `points` `JOIN`ed with the "one geometry type per column" strategy (as per this question), which results in no duplication of data and allows for cross-concept indexes.  However, this has the dependency problem because of dynamic columns.  Possibly there are other options that I am missing, but I suspect that they might depend crucially on precise data sizes and distributions of frequencies of query parameters and such that are much too nuanced for a StackOverflow question.

Comment: You created the dependency here: `RETURNS SETOF my_view`. Use a fixed layout of the result set that is independent of the view. Or review your architecture, this one will cause other issues in the (near) future. I think the maintenance issue you see, is going to get worse if you stick with this

Comment: @FrankHeikens yeah, instead of representing my data with columns and tables I can refactor everything into maximum-normalization EAV-esque syntax.  This is not what I wanted to do (either the refactor OR the normalization).  I'm actually already knee deep into this "create the tables and columns in a plpgsql function" strategy, so I am existing in the (near) future of issues that you mention.  :D  I am hoping to recover somehow without burning the whole system to the ground and starting from scratch.

Comment: What you are trying to do won't work. That seems like a weird use case for materialized views. Search for another solution to the underlying problem (you didn't tell us).

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe if you're interested in the actual use case, I have posted it, but I'm not sure that it will help the question much.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe "won't work" I mean, it works, but the "dynamic SQL structures" strategy seems to be malignant: anything that I build on top of the dynamic `MATERIALIZED VIEW` has to be created and destroyed with it in a carefully-orchestrated sequence of pl/pgsql functions, which makes maintenance/extension very painful, and out-of-reach of the junior team members.  E.g. I could destroy/create `foo` as part of the `make_view` function, but you can see where that leads...

Comment: "*JOIN my points table with the normalized VIEW at runtime, which prevents me from creating indexes that span the geometry/daterange/etc concepts*" - I would think this is the way to go. You can still create different [partial indices](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-partial.html) per concept.

Comment: "*MATERIALIZE my points JOINed with the "one geometry type per column" strategy*" - or alternatively, create on materialised view per geometry type, and then join the appropriate view(s) in your query. Not sure if that helps with your function redefinition, though…

Comment: That's what I meant with "won't work": it will be awkward and painful. I cannot imagine why you want to re-create a materialized view with a different definition.

Comment: "*I have a MATERIALIZED VIEW whose columns change frequently*" - actually I still don't quite understand that part. When you say "*I have many "types" with postGIS geometries in them, [and] each "type" is in a separate table*", doesn't that mean you would only have as many columns in your materialised view as you have type tables? Are you saying your schema (type tables) changes that often? Only during agile development, or during runtime?

Comment: @Bergi "you would only have as many columns in your materialized view as you have type tables" This is exactly the problem.  We get new geographic types relatively frequently, so in the example here I would need new columns for my `MATERIALIZED VIEW` relatively frequently.